# SQLAdapter Like query Not working

Tags: javascript, oracle, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to use LIKE Query but this is not giving me any result set nor it gives me an error. it does give me the result set for the full search, for example, example@test.com but empty for examp

```
var FIND_CUSTOMER_PREPARED_STATEMENT = WL.Server.createSQLStatement(
        "SELECT CUST_ID, " +
        "EMAIL_ADDR, PHONE_NUM, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDR1, ADDR2, CITY_NAME, PROV_ST_CDE, " +
        "POST_ZIP_CDE, NOTES_TXT, DLR_CDE, ANALYS_TXT FROM " +
        "GS_DBA.CUI_CUST_INFO WHERE " +
        "(lower(EMAIL_ADDR) LIKE  lower(?) or ? is null) and " +
        "(PHONE_NUM = ? or ? is null) and " +
        "(lower(FIRST_NAME) = lower(?) or ? is null) and " +
        "(lower(LAST_NAME) = lower(?) or ? is null) and" +
        " Order By LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME"
    );



function findCustomer(emailAddress, phoneNumber, firstName, lastName)
{


    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : FIND_CUSTOMER_PREPARED_STATEMENT,
        parameters : ["%"+emailAddress+"%", emailAddress, 
                      phoneNumber, phoneNumber,
                      firstName, firstName, 
                      lastName, lastName]
    });

}
```

Comment: there is an extra "and" at the end right before the "Order by", is that a cut and paste error?

Comment: did you try passing in null for all the other parameters, hard code it so you are sure it is null, because those are =s

Comment: the extra and was just typo
I found the Solution is 
Format For LIKE Query is
parameters : [new String("%"+emailAddress+"%")